# Question about table/models logic before database generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im trying to make my first side project using rails to learn would you kindly help me understand this?

The basic idea is to have a betting game where one user generates a new bet that can only be accepted by another user (only 2 competitors assigned for each bet, the creator and the other player).

I'm thinking about 2 tables:

1. users
2. bets

Normally I would just have a one to many relationship for the user that created the bet. But I'm confused about the 'competitor' column where another user is also a user with a `user_id`. How can I express this relationship better than this: [image: 1]

After thinking it through it doesn't look like a good setup because I'm renaming a column where I'm storing the `user_id` and having a many to many 'through' model doesn't make sense since it is a "only one competitor can participate in that bet".

I was thinking about a 'one to one through' creating a 'competitors' table like so: [image: 2]

Could you explain to me how to build it in a better way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

just an idea, you can do this with 2 foreign_keys
so user can be as creator or competitors, you can also makesure that creator_id and competitor_id cannot be same value since user cannot bet with self

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator,    foreign_key: "creator_id",    class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :competitor, foreign_key: "competitor_id", class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # as creator to create bet
    has_many: creator_bets,    foreign_key: :creator_id, class_name: "Bet"
  # as competitor to create bet
    has_many: competitor_bets, foreign_key: :competitor_id, class_name: "Bet"
end

@user = User.first
@user.creator_bets.build(...)
  # this to create bet as creator
@user.competitor_bets.build(...)
  # this to create bet as competitor
```

Comment: `belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"` is enough. You don't need to specify `foreign_key` when it can be derived from the name of the association.

Answer (score 1):

> having a many to many 'through' model doesn't make sense since it is a
>   "only one competitor can participate in that bet".

Actually it does. Its is in many ways simpler than having muliple assocations pointing to the same table as you don't have to deal with the situation where a user could be in either column which requires something like:

```
# this gets much messier as you have to deal with more complex problems
Bet.where('bets.user_id = :id OR bets.competitor_id = :id', id: params[:user_id])
```

A many to many association also gives you the option of removing that limitation later with minimal redesign.

Given the following associations:

```
# This represents an event that users can bet on 
# for example Elon Musk being the first man on mars.
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bets
  has_many :users, through: :bets
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bets
  has_many :events, through: :bets
end

# This is the "join model" that joins User and Event
# columns:
# - user_id [bigint, fk] 
# - event_id [bigint, fk] 
# - amount [decimal]
class Bet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

You can simply create a bet by:

```
@event = Event.create!(description: "Elon Musk will be the first man on mars.")
@event.bets.new(user: User.first, amount: 500)
```

You can of course cap the number of users to two by adding a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) or in your controllers. If you only have two you can assume that `event.users.first` is the creator and `event.users.last` is the competitor.